# GWT vs typescript

Tags: gwt, typescript

There are a number of posts on GWT vs javascript but I couldn't find any on GWT vs typescript.

I have about 20,000 lines of code in Java I need to move over to the browser client. However, it's not just recompile in GWT if I go that route. There's a bunch of objects referenced in that code that I need to remove (the existing code is part of a much larger program).

In addition, some low-level classes that are widely used are changing. It's not a big change but these classes are used in a lot of places. So it's really a rewrite either way. A bit smoother rewrite if I got to GWT, but a rewrite nonetheless.

This code also has no GUI or I/O component. It's called by javascript on the client and is used solely to process the javascript objects created and used by the javascript code.

Which leads to my question. What are the advantages and disadvantages of GWT vs typescript?

Comment: Aren't these two options very different? GWT is a full toolkit, while TypeScript is typed JavaScript with some other syntactic sugar.

Comment: This is from the gwtproject.com :  Its goal is to enable productive development of high-performance web applications without the developer having to be an expert in browser quirks, XMLHttpRequest, and JavaScript. That being said if your code is already in Java go with GWT. It won't dissapoint.

Answer (score 3):

Well if I correctly understand you, you want to run `Java` code that was previously run on the Server/Java Applet in the browser without GUI.

I haven't used `Typescript` so I will highlight the advantages of `GWT` (maybe some of them also apply to `Typescript`):

- You having existing `Java` code, so `GWT` is a naturally fit (with `Typescript` you have to rewrite everything).
- You can use [super-source](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideDirectoriesPackageConventions) to override classes and packages that won't work in the `Browser`. This is huge because you will end up with more or less one code base that's capable of running on Browsers, Servers, Java Apps, etc. For example the new google drive spreadsheet (web-app, Android app, etc) is built using this technique.
- GWT supports `tree-shaking` and thus the cost you play is only for what you really use
- Advantages (refactoring, type checks) due to static types

The biggest advantage is that most of your code, can be tested in "plain Java". Only those classes that need emulation have to be tested in the browser. You can use `SuperDevMode` and `SourceMaps` to debug them directly in the browser.

The recently held [GWT.create](http://gwtcreate.com/slides/) conference highlighted also some interesting future improvements to `GWT`. 
There are plans to optimize the compiler so that it produces javascript code that is optimized for the javascript engines (object layout, etc).
There are also some ideas to use `typed arrays` which would benefit performance, especially for computational intense tasks.

Possibly `GWT` could target [asm.js](http://asmjs.org/) which could give you native like performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you and your developers are more comfortable in Java, then GWT is probably the better option.  Also, that allows you to at reuse at least some of your existing Java code without changes, whereas if you port to TypeScript, you'll have to rewrite it all.

Unfortunately, I don't know much about GWT, but can offer the following selling points of TypeScript:

- It is a superset of JavaScript; which means it is easier to get devs up to speed on it who are familiar with JavaScript (assuming they have some experience with static typing).
- The tooling is pretty good, even in non MS environments.  I use WebStorm and Grunt to dev and build; the autocompletion in WebStorm is pretty good.
- It incorporates "Arrow functions" from the ES6 proposal which reduces opportunities for "this" binding errors in the code.
- Even without sourcemaps, the code is pretty easy to debug in modern browsers, because the JS source doesn't change very much from the TypeScript source (minus the types, that is.).  The sourcemap debugging in chrome is pretty good, though, and I hardly ever debug the JS directly.
- If you don't want to deal with static typing, you can just mark a variable as :any (or omit the type) and you are effectively back in carefree JavaScript (some people would view the ease with which one can ignore the type system like this as a disadvantage).

Here are some disadvantages of TypeScript that I have observed:

- The compiler is slowish (though I understand it has been getting faster, its still a few seconds to build most non-trivial projects).
- The non-MS IDEs, while decent as I mention above, could be better; WebStorm is ok, but some tools like refactoring (for example, renaming a function) don't always work well.
- The various forms of module imports can be a pain to deal with, but this is mostly a legacy issue with Javascript not having a standard import format.