# Npm package - GWT or Javascript

Tags: javascript, gwt, npm

I want to build my own npm package/module. It has a lot of functionality.
I would like to know what is the best way to do that. My options are GWT and Javascript.
Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't aware GWT still exists.. it's such an old thing.. of course choose JS!

Comment: It exists and it is great for big projects where u want to manage your code in a more organized way! The thing is I already have something written in GWT and I converted it to so it would fit npm but it doesn't work with my angular2 project. I get errors.

Comment: what do you mean "manage your code"? I thought it was invented because google engineers didn't know javavscript but only Java and they had created this to convert JAVA code into Javascript... you have countless frameworks in Javascript which are already great for organizing code like `elm` or `react` or `vue`.. [here's an article about it](https://www.sitepoint.com/top-javascript-frameworks-libraries-tools-use/)

Comment: What i ment was javascript mixes up scopes,variables etc. U can refer to the wrong variable and it lets u.Any way my problem is I already have something in GWT and don't want to rewrite it all.

Comment: so if you "*don't want*" to re-write it all, why are you asking which should you choose?

Comment: I want to know my options. If GWT is really imposible I will rewrite i guess  But maybe someone will have a solution for me..

Comment: related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/21162156/104380